# Populating a table with data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Newish to MySQL and having a tough time with this problem.
Stuck in progress in my php script.

Here is emailQueue Table (apologies, cant post pictures yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IMHU.jpg

Here is the Students Table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxuD8.jpg

I'd like to grab all the CourseID's from the Students table and add them to columns 1, 2, 3 etc in their respective StudentEmail row. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and any errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","Username","Password","NameOfYourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY StudentEmail"); /* USE ORDER BY StudentEmail */
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$courseid=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['CourseID']); /* STORE THE CURRENT COURSE NAME TO $courseid VARIABLE */

if(empty($studentemail)){
   $studentemail=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['StudentEmail']);
   $id=1;
   /* $studentemail VARIABLE PURPOSE IS TO STORE StudentEmail, FOR LATER CONDITION */
}

else {

   if($row['StudentEmail']==$studentemail){ /* IF $studentemail IS THE SAME WITH THE CURRENT StudentEmail ROW, INCREMENT $id */
   $id=$id+1;
   }

   else { /* ELSE, WHERE $studentemail IS NOT THE SAME WITH THE CURRENT StudentEmail ROW, RESTART THE COUNT OF $id BACK TO 1 AND STORE THE NEW StudentEmail INTO $studentemail */
   $studentemail=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['StudentEmail']);
   $id=1;
   }

}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE emailQueue SET '$id'='$courseid' WHERE StudentEmail='$studentemail'"); /* UPDATE QUERY */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically or use something like:

```
INSERT INTO db.table-destination (c1, c2, c3...)
SELECT a1, a2, a3... FROM db.table-source;
```

You also could try SELECT INTO

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html